# emitter/collector/base vs source/drain/gate terminology?

Tags: transistors, terminology

Sometimes I hear transistors described with emitter/collector/base terminology, and sometimes with source/drain/gate terminology.

What is the reason for having these two different sets of terms?

Comment: Here's [some help](https://www.electronicshub.org/transistors-classification-and-types/). But there at least four kinds of mosfets, several kinds of bipolars, several kinds of jfets, then several kinds of phototransistors, avalanche transistors, etc. There just isn't one set of terms for all of them.

Comment: @periblepsis And you forgot MESFETs, HEMTs, IGBTs, and SITs! There are a lot of types of transistor.

Comment: @Hearth I covered all that and even more in the **"etc"**. You must have missed that part. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They relate to different types of transistors.

Bipolar junction transistors have emitter, collector and base, while field effect transistors have source, drain and gate.

Comment: And IGBTs have emitter, collector, and gate.